# Import OpenAPI/Swagger specification with Kong Enterprise

Tags: api-gateway, kong, kong-plugin

Is it possible to import OpenAPI/Swagger specification with Kong Enterprise edition to generate APIs?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly not, it seems that this has indeed been suggested many many times over the past few years.

See: https://discuss.konghq.com/t/import-swagger-open-api-document-to-create-api-in-kong/510